# Get class properties without those derived from given interface

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a clean way to query Type for properties and filter those that came from an interface?

Let's say I have a class and an interface

```
public interface IFoo 
{
    string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo 
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to get an array of `PropertyInfo`'s that contain only `Baz` property.

Edit:

This is what I have now ... I know it's not perfect, but it kinda does the job.

```
var allProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
var interfaceMethods = typeof(T).GetInterfaceMap(typeof(IFoo)).TargetMethods;
return allProperties.Where(x => !interfaceMethods.Contains(x.GetGetMethod()) || !interfaceMethods.Contains(x.GetSetMethod())).ToArray();
```

Comment: Seems a bit odd to need this. Consider that `Foo` might not, currently implement `IFoo` (this interface might not even exist yet). Your code will return `Bar` and `Baz`. Then someone comes along and decides to create the `IFoo` interface and have `Foo` implement it. This wouldn't normally be considered a "breaking change" - and yet it will change the behaviour of the code you're asking for.

Comment: This dynamic behavior you mentioned it's exactly what I'm looking for. If it implements IFoo I want only `Baz`, and when it's not I want both `Bar` and `Baz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to use [`InterfaceMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.interfacemapping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    private static bool IsInterfaceImplementation(PropertyInfo p, InterfaceMapping interfaceMap)
    {
        var getterIndex = Array.IndexOf(interfaceMap.TargetMethods, p.GetGetMethod());
        var setterIndex = Array.IndexOf(interfaceMap.TargetMethods, p.GetSetMethod());

        return getterIndex != -1 || setterIndex != -1;
    }

    private static PropertyInfo[] GetPropertiesExcludeInterfaceImplementation(Type type, Type interfaceType)
    {
        var interfaceMap = type.GetInterfaceMap(interfaceType);

        return type
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => !IsInterfaceImplementation(p, interfaceMap))
            .ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm already using. I just thought there's a better solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could load all interfaces that are implemented by your class and get all the properties of these interfaces. When getting the properties of your class you can check whether the property is already defined by one of the interfaces:

```
var interfaceProperties = typeof(Foo)
   .GetInterfaces()
   .SelectMany( i => i.GetProperties() )
   .ToList();

var properties = typeof(Foo)
   .GetProperties()
   .Where(p => !interfaceProperties.Any( ip => ip.Name==p.Name && ip.PropertyType==p.PropertyType) );
```

Comment: What if `Foo` contains two `Bar` properties? I.e. `public string Bar { get; set; }
  string IFoo.Bar { get; set; }` - the public one is *not* the implementation of the `IFoo` interface and so (presumably) shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yeah, I was gonna mention that. Thanks!